# Adding a script reference to a SharePoint page

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript

I tried adding a script reference inside the master page but for some reason the script is not responding.

Comment: Please provide an abstract of your code, it is very hard to help you with a question like this without code :)

Comment: There are several different ways to reference a script file in a master page. Which one are you using? Please share the master page lines that you customised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call a script in the masterpage using diffrent techiniques:

From .master

1-Using the SherePoint:ScriptLink

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="core.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false" />
```

From .html

2-Usig the tag script

```
<script src="//html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
```

3-Defining the script directly in the .html master

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  !(function( $ ) {
    if($(".BT-SPminimal .MenuVWidth")[0]!=null){
      var elem = $(".BT-SPminimal .MenuVWidth");
      elem.width("0px");
    }
  })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Make sure that your browser console is not showing any script error.
You can also try to use the document ready to ensure that all the elements are created when the script is called. http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Do NOT use OnDemand="true" when referencing Jquery. It may not load and result in javascript errors.

Answer (score 0):

I am storing my js references in the

> \14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\jQuery

folder and use a  to reference it. Depending on the path where you dropped the js files it would look similar to this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="/_layouts/jQuery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" runat="server"/>
```

You can however also reference it by using a CDN. This will result in some security warnings, when using SSL.